# JPA Query.getResultsList failing on table with composite key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Windows 7
Java 8
Spring 4
Hibernate 5
MySql 5

I have a MySql table "person" defined with a composite primary key

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id BIGINT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  revision BIGINT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  // omitted
  PRIMARY KEY ( id, revision);
```

my ApplicationContext.xml

```
  <!-- omitted  --> 
  <bean id="compositeKey"  class="com.myProject.models.CompositeKey" />
  <bean id="personDao"     class="com.myProject.models.dao.impl.hibernate.PersonDaoImplHibernate" />
```

Class `CompositeKey.java`

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column( name="id", nullable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column( name="revision", nullable=false)
    private Long revision;

    //constructors
    public CompositeKey() {
    //  this.id = id;    commented out due to being a generated value on the sql side
        this.revision = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((revision == null) ? 0 : revision.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if ( !( obj instanceof CompositeKey)) return false;
        CompositeKey that = ( CompositeKey) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId()) && Objects.equals(getRevision(), that.getRevision());
    }

}
```

Class `Person.java`

```
@Entity
@Table( name="person")
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeKey compositeKey;

    // omitted

    //constructors
    public Person() {}

    // getters and setters omitted

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((compositeKey == null) ? 0 : compositeKey.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (birthDate == null) {
            if (other.birthDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!birthDate.equals(other.birthDate))
            return false;
        // omitted
        return true;
    }

}
```

Class `PersonDaoImplHibernate.java`

```
@Transactional
public class PersonDaoImplHibernate implements PersonDao
{
    @PersistenceContext( unitName="pu2")
    private EntityManager em;  //injected from bean

    public void setEm( EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> getAll() {

        List<Person> results = null;

        String sqlcmd = " SELECT p FROM Person p";
        javax.persistence.Query query = em.createQuery( sqlcmd);
        results =  query.getResultList();  // <<<---- fails on this line

        return results;
    }

}
```

and at long last this line in my standalone non-webapp testing program:

```
results =  query.getResultList();
```

throws the dreaded

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=CompositeKey [id=0, revision=0]] was not of the specified subclass [com.myProject.models.Person] : Discriminator: 
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    at com.myProject.models.dao.impl.hibernate.PersonDaoImplHibernate.getAll(PersonDaoImplHibernate.java:43)
    at com.myProject.models.dao.impl.hibernate.PersonDaoImplHibernate$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d0bde1e6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
    at com.myProject.models.dao.impl.hibernate.PersonDaoImplHibernate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6f5d088.getAll(<generated>)
    at TestQueries.testPersonGetAll(TestQueries.java:47)
    at TestQueries.main(TestQueries.java:74)
```

Note that there doesn't seem to be any Discriminator at all - do I explicitly need to set one, and if so what would it be?
The examples on composite keys and `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId` do not mention discriminators.

TIA,

code_warrior

Comment: Can you try changing the name of  "id" field(the class variable) in your class CompositeKey to something else

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...turns out not to be an issue with out with how @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId at all, but rather having hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update had at some point changed the structure of my table.

I prefer to create my own tables manually then build the Java class to match.
DROPing the reCREATEing the table and removing the hbm2ddl statement from my applicationContext.xml  did the trick.

Along the way I learned that javax.persistence.**Typed**Query will make sure getResultsList() returns a list of proper class objects. I've updated the code as appropriate.

Thanks to all,

code_warrior